# How can I get "like something" posts from Facebook stream using FQL

Tags: facebook, stream, facebook-like, facebook-fql, feed

I can see in my feed (on the web FB page) "User_Name likes some_link" post. I also can see it in Facebook application for Android (com.facebook.katana).
But I can't get it using FQL from stream table "SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE filter_key in (SELECT filter_key FROM stream_filter WHERE uid=me() AND type='newsfeed') AND is_hidden = 0".
It's also not in like table.
How can I get those "like something" posts?